# Redirect to a different page after POST using AngularJS

Tags: post, redirect, angularjs, location

After searching and not coming up with a solution I am posting this code snippet for some help.

```
$scope.createAddress = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/addressBook/api/Person',
        data: $scope.person,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $location.path('/addressBook');
    });
}
```

After successfully posting I would like to redirect to a different page. $location.path is not accomplishing this. I have tried $scope.apply() as some others have had success with that. Am I missing something or not understanding what $location is used for? The code is being hit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There should be something listening on that path change, like a `$routeProvider`. Is that the case?

If you need a full page reload to that other (server-side) route you might try `$window.location.href`.

Comment: `$window.location.href = '/addressbook';` and then `$window.location.href;` worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 22):

Remember to inject the dependency to the controller:

```
                                                       |-- inject!
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).               v
controller('AddressController', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/addressBook/api/Person',
    data: $scope.person,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
  }).success(function (data) {
    $location.path('/addressBook');
  });
});
```

Comment: $window.location.href works, but your option - doesnt (but seems better), what can i miss ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me in redirecting. Keep helping.

Answer (score 1):

in your controller add the $location. like this
Ex: app.controller('yourController', function($scope, $location, $http, etc...)
then on your $http should be like this.

```
$http({.... }).success(function(response) { $location.path('/your path')})
```

but make sure that you must add additional location to your $routeProvider Configuration. 
something like:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', 
   function($routeProvider) { 
   $routeProvider.
     when('/yournewlocation', {
      templateUrl: 'yourTemplate/yourpage'
   })
  }
])
```

thats it. well you know what im talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('regCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {

        $scope.submit = function() {
            alert("vf");

            $http.post("http://localhost:3000/insert",function(response,$location){
                if(response!= null){
                $location.path("/login");
            }
            else{
                $state.go('/register');
            }
            });
            }

            }]);
```

my code is like this i am getting only json response after register page its not navigate to another page

Answer (score 0):

simply use `window.location.replace("/Home/Index");`

Comment: Please consider explaining how and why this solves the poblem.

Answer (score -1):

the best way and lightest is

### window.location.replace("/home/list");

Comment: Same solution as other answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/62846667/2227743

Comment: didn't see it, chill !